# How can i change the custom email after the password reset link sent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

After clicking on forgot password. and Send Password reset link, i need to change the email sent to the user. Where do i find this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using laravel 5.3 or above

use `setPasswordResetNotification($token)` on your user model, and return your own notification how ever you want to design it. :) check here.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passwords#password-customization

Answer (score 0):

you can change this view on:

resources=>views=>auth=>emails=>password.blade.php

Good luck :)